# Undefined reference to boost libraries in QT creator on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, boost, mingw32

I am trying to run a QT project on Windows that I have developed on Linux Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I cannot manage it to properly link the boost library. Here is a detailed description of the problem.

I downloaded MinGW from https://nuwen.net/mingw.html, version 13.5, such that the gcc version 5.3.0 matches the MinGW version of QT. The reason to choose this version of MinGW is that it contains the  boost libraries for compression such as zlib. From the command line I compile and run my program without any problems:

*g++ -std=c++11 -w -IC:/MinGW/include -LC:/MinGW/lib bAya.cpp  A.o B.o C.o -o baya -lboost_iostreams -lz -lbz2*

where A,B, C are my pre-compiled object files.

In QT creator I selected the MinGW compiler (C:\MinGW_53\MinGW\bin\g++.exe) and created a new default kit with the compiler.

My .pro file looks as follows:

```
MAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

INCLUDEPATH += C:/MinGW_53/MinGW/include \
C:/Users/kuzk/Documents/src

LIBS += -LC:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/mylib \
-lboost_system \
-lboost_iostreams \
-lz \
-lbz2

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
../src/A.cpp \
../src/B.cpp \
 ../src/C.cpp 

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
../src/A.h \
../src/B.h \
 ../src/C.h
```

The folder C:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/mylib contains my .a files such as libboost_iostreams.a

When I build it, I get many undefined reference errors such as
*error: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy'*

Interestingly, if C:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/mylib contains also libstdc++.a I also get linking errors to std::cout, std::ifstream etc.

I am currently stuck and I will be very helpful for any feedback.

Best,
Konstantin

Comment: Did you rerun qmake?

Comment: Yes, from the Build menu I first run qmake and then I rebuild the project. Still no success...

Comment: Maybe this is more about [tag:qt-creator] than those other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the library path for `boost_iostreams`:

```
-LC:/MinGW/lib \
```

after the line:

```
LIBS += -LC:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/mylib \
```

should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  C:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/mylib is the library path to boost_iostreams. I copied in mylib libboost_iostreams.a and the other necessary .a files. If I give instead C:/MinGW_53/MinGW/lib/ as a library path, I get linking errors even for std::cout. Any idea what this could mean?..

Comment: It's sounds like it's not even linking to the standard library. Try adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Sorry @Konstantin, my mistake that's for `clang`. I use `MinGw` 5.3.0 (that comes with `Qt`) on `Windows` and usually link with: `user32`, `advapi32`, `kernel32`, `gdi32`,`wsock32`,`ws2_32`,`iphlpapi` and `wbemuuid` in that order, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I was able to resolve the problem. Here is what I did. I am using QT 5.7 on Windows 10.

1. I compiled boost using QT's console as described here: http://cpp-qt-mac-win.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/qt-boost-for-beginners-step-by-step.html
2. Then I created a new project and added the paths to boost and the necessary libraries, as described in my question.

An important note. I tried to update the paths in the existing project, by running qmake and then rebuilding the project. I was getting the very same errors as I was getting with the old paths to "standard" boost. Apparently, something was cached and the changes didn't do anything. However, if I give a wrong path to a library it complained. So, QT has very confusing behavior. If someone can explain it, it will be helpful.